# Electron - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS using fetch in a render process

Tags: electron, fetch

I’m having problems using fetch in my electron app.
My app functions fine when built using Electron 3.1.9 but when I try to use anything greater that Electron 4.0.0 fetch works once only, then fails giving an error:

‘Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS’

I’m creating the BrowserWindow like this:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
  show: false,
  x: x,
  y: y,
  width: width,
  height: height,
  titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
  minWidth: 500,
  minHeight: 372,
  backgroundColor: theme,
  webPreferences: {
    //devTools: false,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, './preload.min.js'),
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false
  },
  icon: path.join(__dirname, '../assets/icon/Icon.icns')
})
```

and I’m using fetch in the render process with these settings:

```
init = {

  method: 'get',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa( username + ':' + password ),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  mode: 'cors'
}
```

I can’t work out if it’s a problem with how I’m setting up the BrowserWindow, how I’m setting up fetch, or if I’m trying to do something that’s just not possible in Electron 4+.

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS sounds like you probably have accidentally created a circular redirect. What’s the request URL? Compare to the value of the Location header in the response. You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is the URL in the Location response header the same or similar to the request URL?

Comment: The Location header in the response is identical to the request url

Comment: Well that’s exactly the cause of your problem, then. You understand why, right? That means the server is trying to redirect the request back to the same URL. Again and again and again. But after doing that for a while, eventually the browser hits some configured limit on the number of times it will follow a redirect, and then it gives up and reports ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Yes, I can see that – I just don't know why the code works with electron 3.1.9, but not with electron 4+, and I have no idea what to do to resolve it!